# What does represent a native method jobject parameter?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

When a native C/C++ method is called from an activity method, what does the second parameter of the method represents? As an example, consider a simple procedure defined in, for example, test.cpp:

```
void test( JNIEnv *env, jobject obj )
{
}
```

(i have omitted the true method name for the sake of simplicity). In the activity class, i could declare the native method like:

```
native static void test();
```

If i call it from the onCreate() method of the activity, does the obj parameter 'represents' the activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obj represents the Object reference, or Class reference if the method is static. For example:

```
public class HelloJNI {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hellojni");
    }

    public native String test();
    public native static void staticTest();
}

public class JNITest extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HelloJNI.staticTest() // jobject obj = HelloJNI.class
        HelloJNI hellojni = new HelloJNI();
        hellojni.test(); // jobject obj = hellojni
    }
}
```

Comment: If the method is static you don't have a 'jobect' parameter at all, you have a 'jclass' parameter.

Comment: @EJP, sure. It's the second argument. Casting can work: jclass cls = (jclass)obj;